# ¿Cómo mostrar los datos solamente del usuario logueado?

Tags: php, mysql

El sistema me muestra los datos de todos los usuarios registrados, y yo solo quiero que me muestre los datos del usuario que inicio sesión. Estoy trabajando con **mysql** y **php**
He intentado con:

```
SELECT * FROM nombre_tabla WHERE id='$id'
```

y no me funciona me dice que la variable no esta definida.

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][ el código donde creo la sesión]

---

```
 <?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['nombre'])){
    //echo"no existe session";
}else{
     //echo  $_SESSION['nombre'] ; 
}    
    ?>
<html>
<head>
<title> Estudiante </title>




      <body>
 <form action="" method="POST">



      <td> <h3> Bienvenido(a) <?php echo $_SESSION['nombre'] ?> 
                    <div id="Salir" align="center" > 
                      <a href="cerrar sesion.php">Salir</a> 
         </td>   </h3></div>



        <table>

        <tr>
        <th> <h3>  Cuenta </h3> </th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        include 'conexion.php';
         $query="SELECT * FROM registro WHERE 
          id_usuario='$id_usuario'";
         $resultado=$conexion->query($query);
         while ($row=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){
         ?>


        <tr>
        <td>  Nombre </td>
        <td> <?php echo $row['nombre']; ?> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Correo:   </td>
         <td> <?php echo $row['correo']; ?> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>contraseña:  </td>
        <td> <?php echo $row['contrasena']; ?> </td>
            </tr>                                               



          <?php
         }
         ?>

        </table>



      </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: Puedes dar mas información sobre lo que estas haciendo ?

Comment: necesitamos más información, cómo guardas esa variable $id? de dónde sale? cuando le asignas un valor? es más fácil que te ayudemos si nos muestras algo de tu código.

Comment: Estoy haciendo un sistema que tiene dos tipos de usuario: usuario estudiante, usuario administrador.. el usuario estudiante solo podrá ver su información que ya antes registro para así editarlo, es una cuenta personal... Pero el error es que cuando el estudiante inicia sesión y quiere ver sus datos,  aparece todos los datos de todos los registros de la base de datos y yo solo quiero que muestre su registro, es decir, que el sistema muestre el registro del usuario que esta logueado

Comment: Mi error es que no estoy llamando la variable, pero no se como llamarla en el mismo formulario en el que estoy haciendo el SELECT

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Answer (score 2):

Si el id del usuario lo estas almacenando en la sesión puedes acceder a ella así...

```
session_start();

$idUsuario = $_SESSION['variable'];
```

y hacer el select...

```
$sql = "SELEC * FROM nombre_tabla WHERE id='".$idUsuario."'";
```

Comment: Hola Enrique, acabo de añadir un comentario con mi codigo

Comment: Muéstrame donde creas la sesion

Comment: acabo de publicar una imagen donde hago la sesión.. No se si esta bien hecha pero así la tengo